# Динамически изменяемые заголовки в TabLayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

Всем привет, есть Tablayout, вкладки, которого содержат списки. Количество элементов списка должно передаваться в заголовки tabitem.
Как можно менять заголовки tabitem, при изменении количества элементов в списке.
То есть заголовок tabitem должен меняться также, когда я находясь в списке в нем удаляю и добавляю элементы.

Tablayout находится в одном фрагменте, а списки в другом. То есть при изменении количества данных в одном фрагменте, нужно обновить значение в другом.

Comment: Закладки можно добавлять, удалять, менять текущую. Все это есть в документации. В чем проблема?

Comment: Tablayout находится в одном фрагменте, а списки в другом. То есть при изменении количества данных в одном фрагменте, нужно обновить значение в другом

Comment: [это](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate) тоже есть

Comment: интерфейс применил, все получилось

Answer (score 0):

После изменения списка, необходимо вручную обновить заголовок. Самый простой способ это сделать:

```
val tabItem = tabLayout.getTabAt(0)
    tabItem?.text = "TabName($newValue)"
```